# How to update gnome keyring password?

Tags: security, gnome

Last weak I updated my password on my laptop. Then every time when I logged in, it would prompt for my old password to open the keyring for network manager. To fix this in a terminal I use

```
rm ~/.gnome2/keyrings/default.keyring
```

Is there a different or better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your password through the GUI, it should automaticly synchronize the keyring that stores your WiFi passwords etc. too.

You can also always change it from seahorse's control panel ("Encryption & Keyrings" or something like that in the Preferences).

Answer (score 1):

Inside seahorse:
"Right click on "Login keyring", and select "Change Password", then change it to be the same as your login password. The next time you log in (even with KDE), the Login keyring will be unlocked."

http://linuxfollies.blogspot.com/2012/12/changing-gnome-keyring-password.html