# Update gnome-keyring password via terminal

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-keyring

I am on Arch Linux, but I am still new to it.

I want to update my gnome-keyring password **through the terminal**.

How do I go about doing that?

I've already come across [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/how-to-update-gnome-keyring-password), but the solution there uses a GUI program called seahorse.